# Finding vector equation of image of line through $A$ and $C$ under a reflection with respect to L.

Tags: proof-verification, vector-spaces, vectors, inner-products, 3d

$A(1,-3,2),B(0,-4,5),C(5,0,-3)$ are points in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

I have found the vector equation of the line L through A and B.

$L=i-3j+2k+t(-i-j+3k)$

I have also found the foot of perpendicular from C to L, and hence determine the image of C under a reflection with respect to L.

Let $P$ be the foot of the perpendicular from $C$ to $L$.

$P = (3,-1,4)$

Since P is the midpoint between $C$ and $C'$, I have also found $C'$ which is $C'(1,-2,-5)$

However, now I am stuck at the  below mentioned two questions, I do not know what to use and how to calculate.

iv) Find a vector equation of the image of the line through A and C under a reflection with respect to L.

v) Find the distance from C to L.

Comment: Hints: The reflection of the line through $A$ and $C$ passes through the reflections of these points. The distance between a point and line is measured perpendicularly to the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\vec{BA}(1,1,-3),$ which gives an equation of $AB$:
$$\vec{x}=(1,-3,2)+t(1,1,-3).$$
Let $P(1+t,-3+t,2-3t)$.

Thus, $CP(-4+t,-3+t,5-3t)$ and since $\vec{CP}\cdot\vec{BA}=0,$ we obtain:
$$(1,1,-3)(-4+t,-3+t,5-3t)=0,$$ which gives
$$t=2$$ and $$P\left(3,-1,-4\right).$$
Thus, since $P$ is a midpoint of $CC'$ we obtain:
$$\frac{x_{C'}+5}{2}=3,$$
$$\frac{y_{C'}+0}{2}=-1$$ and
$$\frac{z_{C'}-3}{2}=-4,$$
which gives
$$C'\left(1,-2,-5\right).$$
Now, $$\vec{AC'}\left(0,1,-7\right)$$ and the needed equation it's:
$$i-3j+2k+t(j-7k).$$
Also, we have $$CP=\sqrt{\left(-2\right)^2+\left(-1\right)^2+(-1)^2}=\sqrt{6}.$$